# Rails4.2.6にてjqueryを使ったsweetalertが動かない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, rubygems

rails4.2.6を利用し、ruby2.3.1を使ってます。そこで、モーダルをだしてポップアップを使いたいためsweetalertをgeｍを使って入れましたが、ボタンは動いてくれますが、root_pathの設定通りの動きしかしてくれません。

DeveloperConsoleを見てもエラーは特に出ておらず原因を特定できておりません。

一応、関係しそうな、Turbolinksなどのネットで検索出来るgemは一通りインストールしました。

ですが、動かない状態です。

ソースはsingleview/index.erb.htmlに

```
   <div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
     <%= link_to root_path, { class: :"btn-floating btn-large blue" }, id: "swal-xros5", method: :get do %>
       <i class="large material-icons">add</i>
     <% end %>
   </div>
```

と記載し、これを動かすjqueryに

```
(function(window, document, $, undefined) {
  $(function() {
    $('#swal-xros5').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      swal({
        title: "もちろん",
        text: "あなたはファイルを復元することはないだろう!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "はい、消します!",
        cancelButtonText: "いいえ、キャンセルします",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
      }, function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
          swal("消しました!", "あなたのファイルを消しました.", "成功！");
                } else {
          swal("キャンセルしました", "あなたのファイルは削除されていません :)",
          "失敗");
       }
      });
    });
  });
})(window, document, window.jQuery);
```

と書いております。どうしたら動かすことが出来るのでしょうか？必要な追加情報があれば教えて下さい。ご提示します。

※自己解決。requreの設定がおかしかっただけでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本件解決しました。

requireの位置が間違っていた。

Comment: 質問文にはrequireに関する記述がありませんが、どのように間違えて、どのように解決したかまでを回答に書く必要があると思います。

Comment: かなり前のことなので、変更後は書けますが、変更前は忘れました。